# JavaScript, CSS: Clip to be inside parent DIV

Tags: javascript, css

### Context

I have a bunch of nested DIVs (implementing a simple window system, for learning purposes, with DIVs).

### Problem:

Let divA = child of divB.

Now, ideally, I want the contents of divA to be "clipped" inside of divB.

Thus, if I take divA, and drag it to the right ... as it gets out of the border of divB, I want the parts of divA that are outside of divB to be chopped off and not displayed.

### Question:

How do I do this? How do I use one div to clip / mask another div?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called:

```
.divA {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Comment: Damn you beat me just by a few secs :p

Answer (score 1):

Use the css `overflow` property. Follow **[this link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)** to see what values there are for `overflow`